# Is it necessary to create index externally for auto increment column in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

We have mysql database with auto increment column(id) as primary key for all tables and which is referred in another table as foreign key. We have planned to use index for some of the columns in order to increase the accessing time of the table.

Is it necessary to create index for auto increment column(id) which is referred in another table as foreign key, or by default mysql using index mechanism internally for the column that is referred as foreign key. In any case, If we use index on foreign key, whether it will faster the accessing time ?

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key is used as a unique index, therefor you do not need to add an extra one.

If you want to be sure, you can always add the keywords `EXPLAIN` in front of one of your query to show the execution plan. It will display "use index" in the last column.

Comment: Thanks Damien, it was clear. If we are referring that column in another table as normal field, while accessing that table whether the index is applicable for this case also ?

Comment: If you join from another table, yes it is one of the best index you can have (since it is unique, not only it is indexed but MySQL know that there is only one match).